# What is the best way to auto start multiple existing dependent containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, startup

I have a wordpress container which depends on another mysql container. Basically I want to automatically start them at startup time. As there is dependency between them, I am wondering how could I ensure this dependency.

I've taken a look at `docker-compose`, but it seems that `docker-compose` can only manipulate images instead of containers. As I don't want to mount volumns from container to my host, I don't want to create new container every time.

I've also taken a look at manually create two services using systemd. But it is difficult to decide if mysql is launched(Although the container has been launched, its service still needs more time.).

So what is the recommended way to launch dependent containers at startup time?

Comment: have you looked to the command `docker compose up`? because that's should start all containers in your docker-compose file without recreating it.

Comment: @Sysix But as I didn't launch these two containers using `docker-compose`, how could it identify which two containers I want to launch? In `docker-compose.yml`, it only specifies images but not containers.

Comment: Each of the blocks in the `docker-compose.yml` file describes how to create a container.  (They get destroyed and recreated routinely; that's very normal.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Well, that's what I image. So in this case, it just cannot work as what I expect, right?

Comment: How about `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose start` ?

Comment: @KuanlinChen I think `docker-compose` is just not the right one. It is designed for deployment instead of management.

Comment: If I understand correctly... There is a depends on parameter in docker compose version 2.   https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: `docker-compose` is the solution to this use-case. It will not create a new container if one is already present - even in the `EXITED` state. You can specify in the compose file to pull an email and build too. The `depends_on` param in the compose file will allow you to handle the dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `depends_on` param to manage the dependencies
Here is the compose file for your usecase

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

More Info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

Comment: Well, I don't know if everybody understand what is the key of my question. To clarify, I know how to manage dependencies using `docker-compose`. But if you try it you will find it will launch two new containers instead of using existing ones. What I want is to use two exisiting containers. Anyway, your answer is the closest one. Let's wait for two days to see if there are better solutions or accept yours.

Comment: Running docker-compose down first will delete the old containers. If you have a volume your data will be persistent. You shouldn't have to care if it's new or old containers https://medium.com/@Joachim8675309/devops-concepts-pets-vs-cattle-2380b5aab313

Answer (score 0):

For the exited containers, a `docker-compose up` command will basically pull the latest image and relaunch your container.